# Can I install Ubuntu and then recover files?

Tags: installation, partitioning, windows-7

Currently I have Windows 7 installed on a 1 TB hard drive.

I was wondering whether I could partition my hard drive so that I could have a partition A (800 GB - Empty and unnecessary files) and partition B (200 - Stuff I intend to keep after I install Ubuntu).

So that I could install Ubuntu and have it format partition A. Then once I have installed Ubuntu (13.10 64-bit)

I would like to transfer the files from partition B to new partition A (the one which I have installed Ubuntu over Windows) and delete partition B and expand partition A to take up all of partition B and become only a single partition.

So I want to know if it is possible?

Comment: Why don't you backup whatever you want, and then install Ubuntu.

Comment: I want to avoid doing that.

Comment: yes its possible.

Comment: Yes, possible. But manipulating the partitions always have the chance for a data loss (although small chance). So you should backup beforehand anyway or you are risking your data.

Answer (score 1):

Shrinking a windows partition is trivial using Disk Management. You can then create a new partition to store the files you want to keep. A backup of your data is highly recommended before messing around with partitions unless you don't mind losing your data.

After Ubuntu is installed and the data is copied off partition B you can used gparted to delete the second partition and expand partition A to fill the entire disk.